# How can I suppress the decimal expansion in my axis tick mark numbers on my Plotly.js chart without suppressing number abbreviation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, decimal, plotly.js, yaxis

We are developing an AngularJS application that uses Plotly.js. We would like there to be no decimals on the tick mark numbers on the y axis. So I added this to layout.yaxis: `tickformat: '.0f'`.

This works for removing decimals but for some reason it gets rid of the feature of abbreviating numbers when they get too big (beyond 4 digits).

Here's a screen shot of how the numbers would be abbreviated before the change (12k instead of 12,000, for example):

[image]

And here's after the change:

[image]

We were counting on the abbreviations so that the minimal margin space we have on the left side wouldn't crop the numbers when they get too big (have too many digits).

So here's the question: how can I suppress the decimals without suppressing the abbreviations?

Thanks!